# Split a string using a string as delimiter in awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk, substring

System : Solaris
I am trying to split a string using the delimiter as another string

For example:

---

The main string is : `/as/asdasd/asdasd/root/asdqwe/asd/asssdd/`

I wanna split this into two part from the "root" substring such that

`$1 = /as/asdasd/asdasd/`

and

`$2 =  asdqwe/asd/asssdd/`

This is the code I implemented using FS, but it doesn't work:

```
echo /as/asdasd/asdasd/root/asdqwe/asd/asssdd/ | awk '
BEGIN { FS = "root" } { print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works here, aside from the extra `/` on the front which you don't handle.  Maybe you want `"root/"` as your delimiter?  It may also be necessary to use a newer `awk`; Solaris still ships the ancient V7 Unix `awk` as `/usr/bin/awk`, POSIX-compliant `awk` is `/usr/bin/nawk`.

Comment: What is "doesn't work" exactly?  Also, which `awk` did you use?  There are several, with subtle behavior differences (IIRC one of them wants to see a newline between those blocks, a space isn't good enough).

Comment: well... If i try executing the command above . It splits the string just at the "r" and not "root" .. Hence the output is  "oot/asdqwe/asd/asssdd/" .. its solaris's awk i guess ..since it say /usr/bin

Comment: There should be one in `/usr/xpg6/bin` or whatever it is this week.  Also, there may be an `nawk`.  But `awk` has always used a regexp for `FS`, barring bugs.

Comment: yea .. i read about using regexp with FS too.... its weird...I will try out nawk and let u know... thnks for the input

Comment: UPDATE: Nawk worked brilliantly .... thanks ... If u could update your answer I shall mark it right...

Answer (score 6):

No need to use `awk` , you can do this with your POSIX shell like so:

```
$ var="/as/asdasd/asdasd/root/asdqwe/asd/asssdd/"

$ echo ${var%/root/*}
/as/asdasd/asdasd

$ echo ${var#*/root/}
asdqwe/asd/asssdd/
```

#### Update

If your Solaris version of `awk` isn't working (probably because FS must be chars not strings), then try this method using `split()`

```
awk '{split($0,a,"/root/");$1=a[1] "/"; $2=a[2]; print $1,$2}'
```

Comment: @Siege: is there any way to do this in awk ?? using FS or split function ??

Comment: thanks a lot Siege ... I tried split  with "root" instead of "/root/"... that was the mistake... thanks again

Comment: @siege: i just tried it in Solaris ... apparently  even split has the same issues... sorry for marking it right without trying it

Comment: @Siege: apparently nawk does the trick with both split and FS .. Just thought I would update u ... thanks for the help. :)